# Passing variables between views

Tags: angularjs

I am building an AngularJS app.
I will have a users view which will have a few tabs:

- User Listing
- Account
- Contact
- etc

Basically, everything under "User Listing' should be disabled until a user is selected on the user listing tab. Those tabs will then become active and will have all the details related to the selected user.

I need to pass the id of the selected user into the other tabs so that I can load the model for those users. Do I add the value onto the `$scope`?

For testing, I tried `$scope.id = 4` in my controller for the listing tab.

Then in my view for my account tab, I tried `{{ $scope.id }}` but nothing was printed on the screen.

Comment: are you using ui-router?

Comment: It'd help if you added a plunk or fiddle to show what you've got so far.

Answer (score -1):

You can use to validate a variable to provide user access to routes.

```
$routeProvider
    .when('/somepage' , {
        templateUrl: "templates/template.html",
            resolve: {
                "check": function($location){   
                    if('Your Condition'){ 
                        //Do something
                    } else {
                        $location.path('/');    //redirect user to home.
                        alert("You don't have access here");
                    }
            }
        }
    })
```

You can use service to validate the login. And for show hide menus you can use same reference and use ng-hide or ng-show

Comment: Sorry this doesn't really answer my question. I'm not concerned about validating a login.

Comment: I said, you need to use service to keep instance of id and you may want use the same id to show hide. At the same time you may want to secure your routes for which you can use resolve. Thanks!

Comment: Services seem to be the way to go. Thanks! So If I am simply keeping the ID of the user to, what would be a valid name for this service? Something like `UserIdPersistenceService`?